# How is it possible to find the Wigner function for spin coherent states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coherent-states, wigner-transform

I studied Wigner function distribution for Glauber coherent state and I know that by using this function we can find the probability distribution  for particle's position, but
How can me  find and plot Wigner function for spin coherent states (on sphere) and what kind of information can me get from Wigner function distribution for spin coherent states?

Comment: See the canonical work by Dowling, J.P., Agarwal, G.S. and Schleich, W.P., 1994. Wigner distribution of a general angular-momentum state: Applications to a collection of two-level atoms. Physical Review A, 49(5), p.4101, and many more hits searching “SU2 Wigner function” on Google.

Comment: See also Klimov, A.B., Romero, J.L. and De Guise, H., 2017. Generalized SU (2) covariant Wigner functions and some of their applications. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, 50(32), p.323001.

Comment: Ali, you already have [that one](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/50/32/323001).